# How to add new columns in a datefame and mutate at the same time?

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

I want to count how many of each phenotype (Ki67, cPARP, Negative) cells are in each Tissue Category (Tumour and stroma). I have managed to make 2 additional columns named Tumour and Stroma which separates the two tissue categories into two columns from just one before (Tissue Category).

I want to have 6 new columns in total which will be Tumour Ki67, Stroma Ki67, Tumour cPARP, Stroma
cPARP, Tumour Negative, Stroma Negative, these will have unique cell IDs in them and I can then use the function count to count individual cells in each of these columns. I am attaching pictures of what I have done so far.

This is what I currently have

```
 library(tidyverse)
 library(phenoptr)



 mydata <- read_cell_seg_data(choose.files())
 mydatabackup <- mydata

#what are the unique phenotypes?

unique_phenotypes(mydata)

colnames(mydata)
#what are the unique tissue categories?
TissueCategory_Column <- mydata$`Tissue Category`
length(TissueCategory_Column)

TissueCategory_unique <- unique(TissueCategory_Column)
length(TissueCategory_unique)
#how do you filter on tumour and stroma to remove cells identified in necrosis and background?
filter_tc <- mydata %>% filter(`Tissue Category`!="Background", `Tissue Category`!= "Necrosis")

#how many of each phenotype are there in the tumour and the stroma?
count(filter_tc, 'Tissue Category', Phenotype)
library(tidyverse)

data_wide <- spread(filter_tc, 'Tissue Category', Phenotype)
data_wide
how many of each phenotype are there in the tumour and the stroma?
lapply(unique(filter_tc$Phenotype), function(x){ sum(filter_tc$Phenotype==x) })
```

[Tried count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byh0J.png)

Original table:

[image: Original table]

Answer (score 0):

When you tried using count, it didn't work because you had quotation marks around `'Tissue Category'`. Use backticks instead:

```
count(tissue_tc, `Tissue Category`, Phenotype)
```

When you use quotation marks, you are referring to the string `'Tissue Category'` rather than the column `Tissue Category`.